# extract email address from Notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am trying to extract email addresses from notepad++ using RegEx.

I tried like this

Find and Replace

```
Find: (\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)
Replace : .\1
```

I am loosing email address instead of text. I need remove all text and keep only email addresses in the file. How to do that?

```
    Abilash Perumandla

hi Gunpreet, kindly share your thoughts to Abi@TEKperfekt.com
Pratap Aneel
15d
Pratap Aneel

please share your thoughts to Pratap.kumar@rsrit.com
naveen kumar
15d
naveen kumar
```

Comment: 2 to 4 character for TLD is very poor, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score 9):

You need to match and capture the email with a `(...)` subpattern (so, you do that right), but you need to *just match* everything else (and that part is missing).

Use

Find what: `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)|.`

Replace with: `$1`

Then, you might want to use *Edit* -> *Blank Operations* -> *Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL* menu option.

Comment: Or, replace with `(?1$1\n)` if you have many emails on single lines.